# How to access Sql server online database with my C# windows application

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows

I have windows application using C#, i want to store the data in local SQL SERVER database and as well as online SQL SERVER Database.

Comment: Link1: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C Link2: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4yys16a(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: First store data using SqlConnection with ConnectionString1, then store it again using new SqlConnection with ConnectionString2.

Comment: I want to connect my windows application with online sql server db and as well as want to connect asp.net web application with the same online db. please help, thanks advance

Comment: Stanley@ how to give the ConnectionString for online Database. please give me an example

Comment: Read that links : Beginners Guide to SQL Server with C# (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4416/Beginners-guide-to-accessing-SQL-Server-through-C)

Comment: @Stanley -  They have given example for connection localhost database. But i need to connect with online db....

Comment: This is your friend : https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be asking questions like this here, but here's something to get you started.

```
using(SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection())
{
    cnn.ConnectionString="your connection string";

    // /*e.g.: */ 
    cnn.ConnectionString = "Server=123.123.123.123,1433;Database=DbName;User id=user;Password=pass;";

    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure; //or whatever it is
        cmd.ConnectionTimeout = 0; //or however long you want
        cmd.Connection = cnn;

        cmd.CommandText = "your query";
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SP_PARAM", object); if you are calling an SP

        cnn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); //whatever you are executing
        cnn.Close();

    }
}
```